# (Ruby) sort=1,rating=0,(sort&&rating) == 1 returns true or false?

Tags: ruby

**update: I mistyped 2 variables...so embarrassing. thanks everyone for the effort!**

sorry i find I typed into wrong value for 2 different env, 1st one i set `sort = 0` and `rating=1` but then in irb I set `sort=1` and `rating=0`. since for `a and b` when `a=1` it only evaluates `b` so in the 2nd situation I get `false`. now it comes clear. sorry for the careless, thanks everyone for the effort!

======================

my question:
I have 2 variables, `sort` and `rating`, but both `sort&&rating == 1` and `sort and rating ==1` behave differently in 2 different env as below:

1st, in the debugger env of rails when I execute `rails server --debug`, they all return `true`:

```
(rdb:130) rating 
1
(rdb:130) sort
0
(rdb:130) sort and rating == 1
true
(rdb:130) sort && rating == 1
true
(rdb:130) (sort && rating) == 1
true
```

2nd, in normal irb, they all return `false`:

```
irb(main):001:0> sort = 1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> rating = 0
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> sort||rating
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> sort and rating
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> sort and rating == 1
=> false
irb(main):006:0> sort && rating == 1
=> false
irb(main):007:0> 0 == true
=> false
irb(main):008:0>
```

I know Ruby is so dynamic that...is this situation possible?

Comment: The take-home point here is that 0 is not falsy in ruby.

Comment: Please paste *actual text* instead of images of text.

Comment: And there's a off-topic trick that is relevant to this feature. You can implement a if expression use `condition and if_part or else_part`. -Just for fun, don't use that in formal code.

Comment: You are making this more complicated than necessary.  Just type `1 && 0` and learn what it is.

Comment: yes I did that and it returns `false`, but then why it returns `true` when I use two variables in the first situation?

Comment: @honglonglong Are you sure that `1 && 0` returns false? Note that `0` in Ruby is NOT equivalent to `false`.

Comment: @ShouYa no, I mean `1&&0==1` returns `false`, sorry for the misleading.

Comment: @honglonglong Okay, for the reason, check my answer :)

Comment: @honglonglong I saw that in the debugger, your rating is 1 and sort is 0. However, in the irb, your sort is 1 and the rating is 0. What trick are you playing and what's the point?

Comment: @ShouYa yes, so sorry I also realize that, I already update my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12363/discussion-between-shou-ya-and-honglonglong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in a Boolean context, zero evaluates as true in Ruby, not false.  The only things that are false are `false` itself and `nil`.  Everything else - including empty arrays, empty strings, numerical zeroes - is considered true.

Second, the Boolean operators might not behave quite the way you think.  Since `and` and `&&` are the same except for precedence, and likewise `or` and `||`.  I'll just refer to them generically as `AND` and `OR`.  These are the rules:

`a AND b` returns a if a is false, b if a is true.

`a OR b` returns a if a is true, b if a is false.

So they are really just shorthand for `if a then b else a` and `if a then a else b`, respectively.  The truth tables are the familiar ones, but the actual result is always identical with one of the inputs, rather than some newly-constructed pure Boolean value.

Despite the precedence difference, both versions of this:

```
sort AND rating == 1
```

equate to this:

```
sort AND (rating == 1)
```

So, since sort is zero, which is true, the above expression returns the value of `(rating == 1)`, which is also true (and, in fact, `true`).  Had you gone with `rating AND sort == 1`, it would be `false`, because `sort` is not 1.

You can see where the other results come from if you follow the rules given above.

**Note:** as mentioned by Andrew in the comments, all these various 'true' values are still distinct from `true` itself; 0 may be considered true, but `0 == true` is still false.  (This applies in any language that allows non-Booleans in a conditional context; for instance, in C, any nonzero number is true, but that doesn't mean that any two nonzero numbers are equal.)

Since this can be confusing, especially in verbal or plain text communication where you can't use formatting tricks like true/`true`, Rubyists often take a page from Stephen Colbert and refer to the true-but-not-necessarily-`true` values collectively as "truthy", and their opposites as "falsy" (or "falsey"; I've seen both spellings).  This convention is also used in other languages (notably by Douglas Crockford in his JavaScript book) to distinguish the actual Boolean values from other values that evaluate as true or false in conditional contexts.

**ETA**: As for your result of `sort and rating==1` returning `false` from `irb`, I can't reproduce it.  In both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3, I get the expected output based on the above:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> sort=0
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> rating=1
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> sort and rating==1
=> true
```

Comment: Zero is not `true`, nor is any other number, they are truthy. `0 == true #=> false` but `!!0 == true #=> true`. Likewise `nil` is not false but falsey.

Comment: I didn't say it was `true`, I said it was true.  The English word, not the Ruby value.  Call it "truthy" if you prefer, but the formatting was carefully chosen.

Comment: I still think it's misleading, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: I see. but for `sort=0` and `rating=1` I get `false` from `sort and rating == 1` in irb as I describe above.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this situation is possible, `0` and `1` are evaluated as numbers (`Fixnum` class) so both of them are different from `false`. And anything which is not false must be `true` (with the exception of `nil`).

You can use the `.zero?` method to have an implicit conversion to `boolean`.

In addition the operators `||` and `&&` are different from `or` and `and`. The latter have lower precedence then assignment so when you type

```
sort and rating
```

what actually happens is that statement is not exectued as you would trivially think, because just the second operand is evaluated (so that just its value is pushed as a result).

Think about

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > 4 and 3
 => 3 
ruby-1.9.2-head > 3 and 4
 => 4
```

Comment: "anything which is not false must be true" - not quite.  nil is also false (or "falsey"), despite being distinct from `false`.

Comment: yes, that's the only exception. I thought to have added it with an edit but missed it. Thanks for reporting the fact :)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Ruby's dynamism and everything to do with the fact that in Ruby zero does not evaluate as false, unlike, say, JavaScript or C.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, in Ruby, a logic expression return the first value that decides the expression's result, otherwise, it return the last evaluated value.

Read the following code:

```
true and "foo"
```

As you know that `and` operator must make sure that both values are evaluated as `true`. However, it is not decided yet when just evaluating the `true`, so the conclusive factor, the `"foo"`, which is true, will be accept as the expression's final value.

Another example:

```
false and true
```

Look, the `false` is decisive here, so it will be returned.

And this:

```
false and nil
```

return `false` also, with the same reason.

This rule is also usable for `or` operator, if a value is evaluated as `true` at the left-hand-side of `or`, then the right is not being evaluated any more.

Another concept I think you need to reinforce is, in Ruby, anything expect of `false` and `nil` is `true`.